# jQuery check if input field has a slash inside of it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I can't find how to do this. All I see is questions how to check if any value is present not a specific one.

How can I check if a slash is present inside an input field? So for example: `value="/"` or `value="test/test"` should both trigger the check.

My input field:

```
<input class="form-control" id="pagename" type="text" name="pagename" required="">
```

My jquery:

```
$("body").on("change","#pagename",function(){
  if($(this).val() == '/'){
    console.log('slash is present');
  }
});
```

I found something about regex but can't this be done in a simpler way?

Comment: You can do `$(this).val().indexOf('/') > -1` that will return true, if it exist somewhere in the value

Comment: Similar to the above you can use the "newer" `if ($(this).val().includes("/"))` (but not if you *still* have to support IE11)

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `includes()` method to check this.

```
$("body").on("input", "#pagename", function() {
  if ($(this).val().includes('/')) {
    console.log('slash is present');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do someting like:

```
if (your_string.indexOf('/') > -1)
{
     console.log('slash is present');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The same way you would check if a string has a '/' you can use as mentioned by carsten. `indexOf('/')`

```
$(this).val().indexOf('/') > -1
```

It's cleaner to make $(this).val() a variable if your going to keep referring to it

```
val = $(this).val()
val.indexOf('/') > -1 # Will return true if it contain's '/'
```

Or you can use `includes('/')`

```
 val = $(this).val()
 val.includes('/') # Will return True if it includes a '/'
```

I would say includes is better as it's more readable logically, this will work for all string check's so if you were looking for other characters too. No need to use Regex for simple stuff like this. Regex isn't readable from simply looking at the code.